# How to ignore parameter serialization in C#

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0, xml-serialization

I have an object that I need to serialize in C#, however this object has the property:

```
[XmlElement("NodeConfiguration")]
public NodeConfigurationSerialize NodeConfiguration { get; set; }
```

This property must be ignored during the serialization and must be considered during the deserialization, in other words I need to configure this property in such a way that it is only ignored by the serialization process.

Does anyone know if this is possible? If so, how can I do it?

Note: I am using the Visual Studio 2010 and the .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: If you ignore it during serialization, what would you put into it on deserialization?

Comment: When the object is serialized this property has an invalid value that musn't be on the XML. Afterwards, this property is assigned a valid value by the user and this value is also outputed to the XML without using a serialization process (I actually open the XML using a XDocument and put it there manually).

When my program is initialized I open the XML and deserialized it to read its values. At this point I need to have all of this object's values and the NodeConfiguration property as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think small change in your design is needed.  You need some way to say 'this isn't set':

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
public NodeConfigurationSerialize ? NodeConfiguration { get; set; }
```

When you don't want it set, set it to 'null', when you do, you can set it to whatever you want.  Now you can automatically use serialization/deserialization without needing to manually edit the files.

Comment: Hi, I agree that a lot of rethinking must be done to this software that I am working on, frankly if it were up to me I would just delete everything and start from scratch instead of doing one workaround on top of a another... Anyway I followed your suggestion and set my property to null just before serializing the object to a XML and I got the desired result. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the `System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable` interface:

```
public NodeConfigurationSerialize : IXmlSerializable
{
    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader) 
    {
        this.value = (String)reader.ReadElementContentAs(typeof(String), null);
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer) 
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I think that your suggestion would work too, however I've been thinking on what @DanTheMan said, and I realized that by configuring my class not to serialize this property could bring me a lot of problems in the future, mostly because I would forget I've done this or another programmer would get assigned to this project and if this object ever needs to be serialized than it would take some time until this workaround was discovered and another workaround was made to circunvent it...